# Make parameters 'Optional' in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server, and apologise if the answers are already here. I did look but am not following the answers perhaps I can't apply to my situation or I am getting lost as to why there are elaborate if then constructs.

In simple terms I have a situation where I have quotes. The quotes can be assigned to a client, a site or a water body... Alternatively not all quotes are assigned to any specific client, site or water body either because the quote was entered incorrectly or the client, site or water body is not in our systems yet. I am wanting to construct a stored procedure where any of the three parameters being clientID, siteID, or WaterbodyID can be missing or optional.

I am looking to return for any clientID all records for the client and all records with clientID as Null.  In a similar way if I input the SiteID I don't need or necessarily need to input the clientID, I just want to search for all with this SiteID and any SiteID are null etc.

My attempts so far have not gone well...I can get the records to return with the ClientID and then any Nulls, which looks correct, but as soon as I drop the ClientID and enter just the siteID I am only returning the Nulls for both ClientID and siteID. I want to return siteID (58) in my case, and all records where siteID is Null.

So far what I have is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp_QuoteRequestByID 
    @ClientID INT = NULL, 
    @SiteID INT = NULL,
    @WaterbodyID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Some SQL that I have created in a view and know its working which i added a WHERE clause too as

```
    WHERE        
        ((dbo.Quote.Active = 0) AND 
         dbo.QuoteRequest.Clientid = @ClientID OR @ClientID IS NULL) --Should show both records with clientID and without if no client ID specified
        AND ((dbo.Quote.Active = 0) AND dbo.QuoteRequest.SiteID = @SiteID OR @SiteID IS NULL)
        AND ((dbo.Quote.Active = 0) AND dbo.QuoteRequest.WaterBodyID = @WaterbodyID OR @WaterbodyID IS NULL)
```

I thought this made sense. As I read it if the quote Active is 0 and the @ClientID = Some Value then return all records with ClientID = Some Value and All others with @ClientID Null etc.  This seems to be correct.

However its the next one I have trouble with...

My logic is here that the clientID is null therefore the first part works as null
Then the second part find the @SiteID = 58(in my case) and any other records with a SiteID of Null.  This is not working it is giving only the null records.

I haven't tested the WBID as I figure the same fault will apply as in the SiteID.

Am I misreading the `WHERE` clause? Have I got an error in the construct of the WHERE a simple And and Or reversed? This is my most complex stored procedure to date so nothing would surprise me. Yesterday morning I wasn't even sure what they were used for.

Comment: I am a little lost on the behavior you want when the parameters are `NULL` versus when the data in the tables are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem you're having is with the brackets (or lack of them in the right place).

You seem to be trying logic like   A AND B OR C but you're hoping it will do the B OR C. It won't. It'll do (A and B) OR C. You need to bracket the OR.

Where you have:

```
((dbo.Quote.Active = 0) AND dbo.QuoteRequest.Clientid = @ClientID OR @ClientID IS NULL)
```

You really need:

```
dbo.Quote.Active = 0 AND (dbo.QuoteRequest.Clientid = @ClientID OR @ClientID IS NULL)
```

And do the same for the other two predicates. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to return for any clientID all records for the client and all records with clientID as Null.

First, change your `FROM` clause to use table aliases.  The logic is then easier to write and to read.

Your logic above describes something like this:

```
FROM dbo.Quote q JOIN
     dbo.QuoteRequest qr
     ON . . . 
WHERE q.Active = 0 AND 
      ( (qr.ClientId = @ClientId OR qr.ClientId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.SiteId = @SiteId OR qr.SiteId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.WaterBodyId = @WaterbodyID or qr.WaterbodyID IS NULL)
      )
```

But I don't think that is the logic you really want.  If you want the logic that the passed in parameters act as "ALL", then:

```
WHERE q.Active = 0 AND 
      ( (qr.ClientId = @ClientId OR @ClientId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.SiteId = @SiteId OR @SiteId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.WaterBodyId = @WaterbodyID or @WaterbodyID IS NULL)
      )
```

If you want that behavior AND for `NULL` values in the *tables* to match regardless, then:

```
WHERE q.Active = 0 AND 
      ( (qr.ClientId = @ClientId OR @ClientId IS NULL OR qr.ClientId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.SiteId = @SiteId OR @SiteId IS NULL OR qr.SiteId IS NULL) AND
        (qr.WaterBodyId = @WaterbodyID or @WaterbodyID IS NULL OR qr.WaterBodyId IS NULL)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, with no sample data, what you want is to be able to specify filter values with `@ClientId`, `@SiteId` and `@WaterBodyId`. If you specify a filter value, i.e. the variable is not `NULL`, then you want all rows where either: (1) the corresponding field matches the specified value *or* (2) the corresponding field is `NULL`.

As Dr. Linoff suggests, table aliases are helpful here:

```
where q.Active = 0 and (
  ( @ClientId is not NULL and ( qr.ClientId = @ClientId or qr.ClientId is NULL ) ) or
  ( @SiteId is not NULL and ( qr.SiteId = @SiteId or qr.SiteId is NULL ) ) or
  ( @WaterBodyId is not NULL and ( qr.WaterBodyId = @WaterBodyId or qr.WaterBodyId is NULL ) ) )
```

If you specify more than one filter then they will be "ored", i.e. if *any* of the conditions are met then the row will be returned.

Note that if you don't specify a filter value that no rows will be returned. You could add a fallback to handle that case:

```
or ( @ClientId is NULL and @SiteId is NULL and @WaterBodyId is NULL )
```

Depending on where you add it you can have it return all inactive (`q.Active = 0`) rows or all rows.

Aside: You could replace `qr.ClientId = @ClientId or qr.ClientId is NULL` with `Coalesce( qr.ClientId, @ClientId ) = @ClientId`. Shorter, but not clearer.